# Change the queue driver in Laravel 5.1 at runtime?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I'm using beanstalkd as my queue driver:

```
# /.env
QUEUE_DRIVER=beanstalkd

# /config/queue.php
'default' => env('QUEUE_DRIVER', 'sync'),
```

and a queue-able job

```
# /app/Jobs/MyJob.php
class MyJob extends Job implements SelfHandling, ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;
    ....
    ....
}
```

This works great when I dispatch the job via a controller, but I'd like one particular route to use the *sync* driver instead of the *beanstalkd* driver when dispatching the job. Middleware seemed like the answer here

```
# /app/Http/Controllers/MyController.php
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $this->dispatch(new \App\Jobs\MyJob());
}

# /app/Http/routes.php
Route::post('/create', ['middleware' => 'no_queue', 'uses' => 'MyController@create']);

# /app/Http/Middleware/NoQueue.php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request);
    config(['queue.default'=>'sync']);
    return $response;
}
```

However, the job is still being pushed to the beanstalkd queue.

In other words, how does one change the queue driver at runtime when dispatching a job from a controller?

EDIT:
Calling **config(['queue.default'=>'sync'])** *does* seem to work in an Artisan command, just not from an Http Controller...

```
# /app/Conosle/Commands/MyCommand.php

class ScrapeDrawing extends Command
{
    use DispatchesJobs;
    ...
    ...
    public function handle()
    {
        config(['queue.default'=>'sync'])
        $this->dispatch(new \App\Jobs\MyJob());
    }
}
```

Comment: What about `Queue::driver('sync')->push(new \App\Jobs\MyJob());`

Comment: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Queue\Queue::driver()`

Answer (score 3):

Solved by using this in my controller method:

```
# /app/Http/Controllers/MyController.php
public function create(Request $request, QueueManager $queueManager)

    $defaultDriver = $queueManager->getDefaultDriver();

    $queueManager->setDefaultDriver('sync');

    \Queue::push(new \App\Jobs\MyJob());

    $queueManager->setDefaultDriver($defaultDriver);
}
```

In my case, \Queue:push() seems to pay attention to the driver change at runtime whereas $this->dispatch() doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at what your middleware does - **$next($request);** is the code that executes the request. As you can see, you are changing the config after request is already processed. Change

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  $response = $next($request);
  config(['queue.default'=>'sync']);
  return $response;
}
```

to

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
  config(['queue.default'=>'sync']);
  $response = $next($request);
  return $response;
}
```

Comment: Good catch, however still no dice. Job is still being pushed to beanstalkd.

Comment: Are you sure? I did that in one of our middleware and it works - instead of database queue I got SyncQueue object. How are you checking which queue is used?

Comment: I'm seeing the job being processed in ptrofimov/beanstalk_console. Are you setting the queue driver in .env?